# How to handle the "alt" keystroke with windows api c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to handle the "alt" keystroke but nothing happen.
I use C++ with the windows and winuser libraries

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *hook=(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    std::string input;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP) {
         input = Key::get(hook->vkCode, 1);
    } 
    else if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
    input = Key::get(hook->vkCode, 0);
    }
    Key::print(input);
    return 0;
}
```

I can handle all the keyboard, except the "alt" key in the Key::get() function.
Does anyone know how to handle it ?

```
std::string get(int code, int up) {
    std::string input;
    switch(code) {
        case 0x12: input = "[ALT]"; break;
    }
    return input;
```

[EDIT] It's actually a WM_SYSKEYDOWN message that should be use to handle alt key, i thought the last code i posted would suffice to see where was the problem. I didn'd post the procedure and there's where the issue is. Thanks to all for your answers.

Comment: Where did you get `code` from? There is not enough information to be able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: To add to what Microsoft legend Raymond Chen said above, all questions on Stack Overflow need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be answerable. See the link for advice on creating one.

Comment: A guess - pressing Alt posts a `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` message rather than a `WM_KEYDOWN` message, and you're not handling both of them.

Comment: Nice guess. Thanks.

Comment: LowLevelKeyboardProc is strange.. among everything  it doesn't receive repeated  key down messages by design, in some situation it "sees" only keyup messages for modifier keys.

Comment: Please post the code that has the problem and post the solution as an answer. Don't hoard the answer. That does nothing to help others with the same problem.

Comment: It does the job for alpha, numeric, ctrl, shift and shift lock. I have an issue with shift lock but i can correct it. Then i'll implement the alt combo in my Key::get() function. If you can tell me which situations, i can write exceptions procedures to bypass it. Thanks a lot for your intervention. I appreciate it.

Comment: For `SendInput`, use `VK_MENU` for the ALT key, and `VK_LMENU` and `VK_RMENU` for the left and right ALT keys. If you need to use the sometimes referred to "menu" key (it's actually called the Applications key) then use `VK_APPS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0x12  look like something Windows API would return, but how you obtain that? but checking for it is not enough. Avoid using "magic" numbers, that code is named VK_MENU.

> **WM_KEYDOWN message**
>
> Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a nonsystem key is
> pressed. A nonsystem key is a key that is pressed when the ALT key is
> not pressed.
>
> *wParam*  The virtual-key code of the nonsystem key. See Virtual-Key
> Codes.
>
> *lParam*  The repeat count, scan code, extended-key flag, context
> code, previous key-state flag, and transition-state flag, as shown
> following
>
> - 0-15 The repeat count for the current message. The value is the number of times the keystroke is autorepeated as a result of the user
>   holding down the key. If the keystroke is held long enough, multiple
>   messages are sent. However, the repeat count is not cumulative.
> - 16-23 The scan code. The value depends on the OEM.
> - 24 Indicates whether the key is an extended key, such as the right-hand ALT and CTRL keys that appear on an enhanced 101- or
>   102-key keyboard. The value is 1 if it is an extended key; otherwise,
>   it is 0.
> - 25-28 Reserved; do not use.
> - 29 The context code. The value is always 0 for a WM_KEYDOWN message.
> - 30 The previous key state. The value is 1 if the key is down before the message is sent, or it is zero if the key is up.
> - 31 The transition state. The value is always 0 for a WM_KEYDOWN message.
>
> **WM_SYSKEYDOWN message**
>
> Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when the user presses the
> F10 key (which activates the menu bar) or holds down the ALT key and
> then presses another key. It also occurs when no window currently has
> the keyboard focus; in this case, the WM_SYSKEYDOWN message is sent to
> the active window. The window that receives the message can
> distinguish between these two contexts by checking the context code in
> the lParam parameter.
>
> *wParam*  The virtual-key code of the key being pressed. See Virtual-Key
> Codes.
>
> *lParam*  The repeat count, scan code, extended-key flag, context
> code, previous key-state flag, and transition-state flag.

If you use Get\PeekMeessage, something like this would explain possibilities:

```
// Receives a WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYDOWN or WM_SYSKEYUP message and 
// returns a virtual key of the key that triggered the message.
// 
// If the key has a common virtual key code, that code is returned. 
// For Alt's and Ctrl's, the values from the KeyCodes enumeration are used.
int translateKeyMessage (MSG& Msg);

// Virtual key codes for keys that aren't defined in the windows headers.
enum KeyCodes
{
    VK_LEFTCTRL = 162,
    VK_RIGHTCTRL = 163,
    VK_LEFTALT = 164,
    VK_RIGHTALT = 165
};


int translateKeyMessage (MSG& Msg)
{
    // Determine the virtual key code.
    int VirtualKeyCode = Msg.wParam;

    // Determine whether the key is an extended key, e.g. a right 
    // hand Alt or Ctrl.
    bool Extended = (Msg.lParam & (1 << 24)) != 0;

    // If this is a system message, is the Alt bit of the message on?
    bool AltBit = false;    
    if (Msg.message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN || Msg.message == WM_SYSKEYUP)
        AltBit = (Msg.lParam & (1 << 29)) != 0;

    if ((Msg.message == WM_SYSKEYUP || Msg.message == WM_KEYUP) && !Extended && !AltBit && VirtualKeyCode == VK_MENU)
    {
        // Left Alt
        return KeyCodes::VK_LEFTALT;
    }

    // Left Ctrl
    if (!Extended && !AltBit && VirtualKeyCode == VK_CONTROL)
    {
        // Peek for the next message.
        MSG nextMsg;
        BOOL nextMessageFound = PeekMessage(&nextMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);

        // If the next message is for the right Alt:
        if (nextMessageFound && nextMsg.message == Msg.message && nextMsg.wParam == VK_MENU)
        {
            //
            bool nextExtended = (nextMsg.lParam & (1 << 24)) != 0;

            //
            bool nextAltBit = false;    
            if (nextMsg.message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN || nextMsg.message == WM_SYSKEYUP)
                nextAltBit = (nextMsg.lParam & (1 << 29)) != 0;

            // If it is really for the right Alt
            if (nextExtended && !nextAltBit)
            {
                // Remove the next message
                PeekMessage(&nextMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

                // Right Alt
                return KeyCodes::VK_RIGHTALT;
            }
        }

        // Left Ctrl
        return KeyCodes::VK_LEFTCTRL;
    }

    if (Msg.message == WM_SYSKEYUP && !Extended && AltBit && VirtualKeyCode == VK_CONTROL)
    {
        // Peek for the next message.
        MSG nextMsg;
        BOOL nextMessageFound = PeekMessage(&nextMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);

        // If the next message is for the right Alt:
        if (nextMessageFound && nextMsg.message == WM_KEYUP && nextMsg.wParam == VK_MENU)
        {
            //
            bool nextExtended = (nextMsg.lParam & (1 << 24)) != 0;

            //
            bool nextAltBit = false;    
            if (nextMsg.message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN || nextMsg.message == WM_SYSKEYUP)
                nextAltBit = (nextMsg.lParam & (1 << 29)) != 0;

            // If it is really for the right Alt
            if (nextExtended && !nextAltBit)
            {
                // Remove the next message
                PeekMessage(&nextMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

                // Right Alt
                return KeyCodes::VK_RIGHTALT;
            }
        }
    }

    // Right Ctrl
    if (Extended && !AltBit && VirtualKeyCode == VK_CONTROL)
        return KeyCodes::VK_RIGHTCTRL;

    // Left Alt
    if (!Extended && AltBit && VirtualKeyCode == VK_MENU)
        return KeyCodes::VK_LEFTALT;

    // Default
    return VirtualKeyCode;
}
```

Comment: Best not to guess. Wait for the user to provide clarification and only when the question is complete write an answer. Otherwise we have the situation where we appear to say that this question is valid in this form.

Comment: This was the perfect answer. Thanks a lot Swift.